# if links contains last part of window location

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to add a class to a parent of link that contains last part of window location for further styling.

the basic html would look like this

```
<li>
  <a href="whatever">Some link</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="subnavli">
      <a href="somelink.com/somethinginthemiddle/lastpart">Link Text</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

and the js/jquery i'm trying to use is

```
function getLastSegmentOfPath(url) {
    var matches = url.match(/\/([^\/]+)\/?$/);
    if (matches) {
        return matches[1];
    }
    return null;
}

var endPath = getLastSegmentOfPath(window.location.href);

  $(".subnavli a").each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('href').contains(endPath)) {
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('active5');
    }  
  });
```

As you can probably guess, it's not working.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gvmhtLud/  you need this? p.s. click 'run'.

Comment: nothing happens when i click run

Comment: Hm.. i see - try in firefox. However, try to make tests outside fiddle...

Comment: it does work in firefox, but the firefox is not the only one out there...

Answer (score 0):

contains() was problem. Now should work. contains() function is something else: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/ And, also there is contains selector, but that's another story...

```
function getLastSegmentOfPath(url) {
    var matches = url.match(/\/([^\/]+)\/?$/);
    if (matches) {
        return matches[1];


    }
    return null;
}

endPath = getLastSegmentOfPath(window.location.href);
 console.log(endPath);
  $(".subnavli a").each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf(endPath)) {
      $(this).parent().parent().prev('a').addClass('active5');
    }  
  });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/gvmhtLud/2/